# Using ggplot in R to create a line graph for two different groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I'm trying to create a line graph depicting different trajectories over time for two groups/conditions. I have two groups for which the data 'eat' was collected at five time points (1,2,3,4,5). 
I'd like the lines to connect the mean point for each group at each of five time points, so I'd have two points at Time 1, two points at Time 2, and so on.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
#Example data
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
eat <- sample(1:7, size = 30, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), each = 5),
                 Condition = rep(c(0, 1), each = 15),
                 time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 eat = eat
)
df$time <- as.factor(df$time)
df$Condition <- as.factor(df$Condition)

#Create the plot.
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = eat, fill = Condition)) + geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, colour = "red", geom = "line")
```

The problem is, I need my lines to go horizontally (ie to show two different colored lines moving across the x-axis). But this code just connects the dots vertically:

[image: Here's what it looks like:]

If I don't convert `Time` to a factor, but only convert `Condition` to a factor, I get a mess of lines. The same thing happens in my actual data, as well.

[image: example graph result]

I'd like it to look like this [image: like this] aesthetically, with the transparent error envelopes wrapping each line.  However, I don't want it to be curvy, I want the lines to be straight, connecting the means at each point.

Comment: `factors` are discrete. It seems like you want a continuous x-axis, so one good step will be to *not* convert `time` to a factor.

Comment: Please clarify how you want the "error envelopes" to be calculated.

Comment: I am hoping there's a way to calculate +/-1 standard error (or standard deviation).

Comment: I'm also confused about the meaning of "id" in your data. What are the two lines you want - one for each condition? Does `id` need to be accounted for in the plot?

Comment: Oh, no, id is participant id. It doesn't need to be plotted. Yes, I want two lines- one for each condition. x=time and y=eat.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the lines running in straight segments through the means of each time, with the range set to be the standard deviation of the points at the time. One `stat.summary` makes the mean line with the `colour` aesthetic, the other makes the area using the inherited `fill` aesthetic. `ggplot2::mean_se` is a convenient function that takes a vector and returns a data frame with the mean and +/- some number of standard errors. This is the right format for the`fun.data` argument to `stat_summary`, which passes these values to the `geom` specified. Here, `geom_ribbon` accepts `ymin` and `ymax` values to plot a ribbon across the graph.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(12345)
eat <- sample(1:7, size = 30, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(
  Condition = rep(c(0, 1), each = 15),
  time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  eat = eat
)
df$Condition <- as.factor(df$Condition)

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = eat, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21, colour = "black") +
  stat_summary(geom = "ribbon", fun.data = mean_se, alpha = 0.2) +
  stat_summary(
    mapping = aes(colour = Condition),
    geom = "line",
    fun.y = mean,
    show.legend = FALSE
    )
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Beat me to it! (Just add `show.legend = FALSE` in the second `stat_summary` and I will upvote) ;)

Comment: @Calum You Awesome- that's perfect. Thanks! One question though: I'm guessing 'stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "ribbon", alpha = 0.2)' creates the standard error ribbon around each line? I don't quite understand how each line defines which group to calculate the mean and SE from?

Comment: Added some more explanation. I suggest you play around with `geom_ribbon` to see how it works. Often it is simpler to do a transformation and then apply geoms, but stats let you do it all in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best guess at what you want:

```
# keep time as numeric
df$time = as.numeric(as.character(df$time))
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = eat, group = Condition)) +
    geom_smooth(
        aes(fill = Condition, linetype = Condition),
        method = "lm",
        level = 0.65,
        color = "black",
        size = 0.3
    ) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Condition))
```

[image]

Setting the `level = 0.65` is about +/- 1 standard deviation on the linear model fit.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will get you most of the way there

```
  library(tidyverse)

  eat <- sample(1:7, size = 30, replace = TRUE)  
  tibble(id = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), each = 5),             
         Condition = factor(rep(c(0, 1), each = 15)),
         time = factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 6)),
         eat = eat) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = eat, fill = Condition, group = Condition)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21) +
  geom_smooth()
```

`geom_smooth` is what you were looking for, I think.  This creates a linear model out of the points, and as long as your `x` value is a factor, it should use the mean and connect the points that way.